# Como exibir a hora no formato 24 horas usando datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando exibir no formato PM, mas sempre que seleciono no timepicker ele seta como AM.

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    lang: 'pt-BR',
    timepicker: true,
    format: 'd/m/Y h:i'
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu seleciono a hora, exemplo 21:00 ele seta como 09:00:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples, você esta informando no formato da hora o `h` em minusculo, sendo que para que funcione em modo *24hs* você deve informar ele em maiúsculo `H`.

```js
jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker: true,
    format: 'd/m/Y H:i'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```

> Podes ver na [documentação](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#TimePicker) esse dentre outros exemplos.

Comment: Caramba, não acredito que era isso velho, meu Deus do céu kkkk, muito obrigado você salvou meu dia haha!

Comment: Isso acontece com qualquer um **:)**

Answer (score -4):

<-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->

<-- language: lang-js -->

```
jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker: true,
    format: 'd/m/Y H:i'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```

```js
jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker: true,
    format: 'd/m/Y H:i'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```